# one external swf playing over another, after a timer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two external .swf's.  I need to have the first one played on load and then the second swf needs to be played over the first one after a timer.

If someone could help me out with a code I would greatly appreciate it!
(note: I'm not that good with actionscript, so bear with me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a timer, on timer event create a Loader object with the URL of the second SWF (it can only be loaded from the same server the parent SWF gets loaded) and add it as a child of the parent SWF.

The code examples are easily found on google, like this one:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html

Comment: the link did not work.
can you provide a sample code for this?

Comment: sorry, the last 0 was cut off the link, here it is:    http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html